# Выбор дистрибутива Linux

Tags: ос, linux

**Доброго времени суток.**

Меня зовут Максим и Я работаю программистом. Администрирование серверов и рабочих станций даже близко не входит в мои обязанности, но все же есть желание научится профессионально работать с ОС, построенных на базе ядра Linux.

Долгое время использовал именно Windows, в сторону других ОС даже не смотрел. Последние 2-3 года работаю с Ubuntu и успел изучить оную до необходимого мне уровня. Чувствую, что нужно сменить дистрибутив ибо Я только краем уха слышал про: Slackware, Arch, Fedora, openSUSE, Mandriva и тд. То есть если меня посадить работать за ПК под управлением одного из вышеперечисленных дистрибутивов Linux, то, боюсь, что Я про100 "потеряюсь", когда дело дойдет до более-менее серьезных манипуляций. Желаю устранить эту проблему.

Прошу помочь с выбором дистрибутива, который удовлетворяет следующим критериям:

- Разработка не заброшена и не приостановлена
- Наличие поддержки как десктопов, так и серверов
- Наличие GUI
- Не Ubuntu и даже не Debian
- Поддержка архитектуры x86-64

И еще попрошу не холиварить на тему лучшего дистрибутива. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы хотите поменять дистрибутив?

Comment: @aza1io, хочу научится работать с другими популярными дистрибутивами. Зачем? Хз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUSE (в т.ч. open) - хорошая поддержка и продолжает развиваться.

Fedora - то же самое.

Solaris - своеобразная весч, но зато есть вариан , работающий на "серьезных" серверах SPARC (Scalable Processor ARChitecture — масштабируемая архитектура процессора)

Slackware - забудь, это для гурманов спец. задач

Comment: Solaris никаким местом не Linux.И вообще про что вы говорите? Sun Solaris, OpenSolaris, OpenIndiana и Illumos или что-то гибридное а-ля Nexenta? Это все Солярисы ))

Comment: Anton Shevtsov, имею ввиду первоисточник, SunOS, которая с текущего выпуска перестает считаться UNIX. (см сайт первоисточника)Кстати суся тоже поддерживает "серьезгые" архитектуры, в т.ч. тот же SPARC и P-IV.Я это к тому, что если уж что и изучать, то это должно пригождаться хотя бы в будущем...

Answer (score 2):

На работе знакомство с линуксом начал с Gentoo. После нее ни один дистрибутив не страшен. Рекомендую! Правда сейчас обленился и больше дебианом/убунтой пользуюсь.Из плюсов:

- поймешь как устанавливается система,
- в начале не ставится никаких лищних   программ,
- настраивается полностью   под собственные нужды,
- установка пакетов с кастомными настройками   зависимостей, компилится именно под   твою систему и настройки,
- не rocket science, но многих пугает такой подход :)
- изза такого подхода к настройке/установке нет разделения сервер-десктоп, что настроишь то и будет

В последних версиях есть установка из гуя. Для начала можно попробовать не чистую генту, а Calculate Linux, которая больше заточена под десктопный стиль ибо гуй из-коробки.

Answer (score 2):

Ну тут разговор короткий. Всем вашим пунктам полностью удовлетворяет Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) (подписка на обновления платная), он же CentOS (полностью бесплатный, отличие в отсутствии логотипа RedHat), ближайший родственник Fedora (или более адаптированный под местное население Russian Fedora Remix).

Резюмируя, можно отметить, что это платформы для промышленного внедрения (т.е. стандарт для предприятий), кроме Fedora - это больше домашний дистрибутив. Есть подразделение на Server/Workstation, есть i686,x86_64 и некоторые другие архитектуры. Апдейты и стабильность. Очень долгий период поддержки (не касается Fedora).

Answer (score 0):

Всем требованиям отвечает OpenSuSE(SLES)Практически все библиотеки Python.Следующим этапом я бы рассмотрел centos.

Answer (score 0):

затрудняюсь что либо предлагать. сам работаю на Федоре и Убунту. убунту проще, так как почти близко к винде подточена. Федора посложнее. для меня. пробовал Опен сузе. не понял.Центос не смог настроить под свои нужды. пробовал Арч потерял время и всё что имел на компе сложновато после винды в черном экране работать не представляешь что произойдёт после той или другой кнопки Сциентифик тот же ред хат. но это мои личные.впечатления. очень жалею что не учился раньше програмировать. было бы более понятно. определятся всёравно самому.

Answer (score 0):

Для программиста лучше всего Gentoo, потому что большая часть пакетов распространяется там в исходниках с открытым кодом. Я как-то сам этим баловался, но комп тогда слабый был, и для установки или обновления чего-либо нужно было ждать часа полтора компиляции. Тут я сдался, и перешёл на Kubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Slackware тоже не плохая система, особенности свои конечно есть, но например от тойже Gentoo отличается простотой своей. Из недостатков - не очень большое количество готовых пакетов (хотя если поискать есть довольно таки большие репозитории) и отсутствие контроля зависимостей. Также особенностью этого дистрибутива является отсутствие частых обновлений, новые версии выходят с довольно таки радикальными изменениями. Но отсутствие постоянных обновлений предотвращает падение системы в результате кривоватых обновлений.